# Foreach for double linked list without macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am using [double linked list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554296(v=vs.85).aspx) and want to optimize it usage.
I have a lot of places where I iterate throw all list elements. I want to use following defines:

```
//
// Iterates through all protected files
//
#define FOR_EACH_PROTECTED_FILE_START(protectedFile) \
    for(PLIST_ENTRY protectedFileEntry = filterData.ProtectedFilesHead.Flink; protectedFileEntry != &filterData.ProtectedFilesHead; protectedFileEntry = protectedFileEntry->Flink) { \
    protectedFile = CONTAINING_RECORD(protectedFileEntry, MY_PROTECTED_FILE_TYPE, EntryLink);


#define FOR_EACH_PROTECTED_FILE_END }
```

Is there way to do this without macro (macro is evil bla..bla.bla) to not put this constructs every place I want to iterate foreach file?

How do you like this style?

Comment: Write it in a function that a accepts a visit callback? Macros are evil only if you give them more credit than they deserve. I wouldn't put the braces `{}` in the macros, that's just cumbersome and un-intuitive.

Comment: @StoryTeller a function for every forech, even small logic (1-2 row)? is it better then macros? Without  braces i need two macrosis everywhere FOR_EACH_PROTECTED_FILE_START and CONTAINING_RECORD.. not good too

Comment: Hey, it was you who wanted to axe the macros

Comment: @BransDs: "A function for every for each[..]? Is it better than macros?". Yes, it is indeed better than macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the boilerplate logic into a function, which controls the loop and return a state.

```
inline int iterate_protected_files(ProtectedFile_t* current, /*other state data*/)
{
  /* Bolierplate stuff to get next file*/
  *current = whatever;
  return current_exists;
}

...

while (iterate_protected_files(&protectedFile))
{
  /* do stuff with a protected file */
}
```

Comment: Consider addind the keyword `inline` to `iterate_protected_files`.

Comment: @rslemos, should have done it from the start. But had very little work actually done with C99 :)

Comment: Also, you can't change `current` value itself (well, you can, but is useless since the caller won't view it). Either it does suffice to change `current` contents, or the formal parameter should be double pointer (`ProtectedFile_t** current`) and changes are made to contents of this (`*current = whatever`).

Answer (score 1):

You can stick to macro, but avoiding the braces in the macro itself:

```
#define FOR_EACH_PROTECTED_FILE(protectedFile) \
    for( \
        PLIST_ENTRY protectedFileEntry = filterData.ProtectedFilesHead.Flink, \
        protectedFile = CONTAINING_RECORD(protectedFileEntry, MY_PROTECTED_FILE_TYPE, EntryLink); \
        protectedFileEntry != &filterData.ProtectedFilesHead; \
        protectedFileEntry = protectedFileEntry->Flink, \
        protectedFile = CONTAINING_RECORD(protectedFileEntry, MY_PROTECTED_FILE_TYPE, EntryLink) \
    )
```

Use it like a for (as it actually is):

```
...
FOR_EACH_PROTECTED_FILE(protectedFile) {
    <code that deals with protectedFile>
}
```

Comment: Why is there two times row:  protectedFile = CONTAINING_RECORD(protectedFileEntry, AAFILEFILTER_PROTECTED_FILE, EntryLink) ?

Comment: For the first iteration and then for all the other iterations. Think of `for(i = 0; ...; i = i+1)`: see? `i` is assigned first to initialize the loop, and once again every new iteration.

Comment: i think CONTAINING_RECORD will crash for the list head, but idea is interesting

Comment: @BransDs, yes this solution may break depending on what the macro `CONTAINING_RECORD` expands to. Anyway you can draw a lot of ideas from [include/linux/list.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h), in my opinion a brilliant piece of code and a source from where you can learn a lot about advanced C constructions.

Comment: @BrandDs, also whether the macro `CONTAINING_RECORD` will break or not depends on what it expands to (for example, cannot expand to a block of code, though a block expression will fit). If it ever breaks just because of list head, then it would break anyway on your implementation (since your assignment happens since de first iteration). What you should care for is actually the last iteration, which in your code don't "call" it.

Comment: Just a correction on my previous comment: what I called "block expression" is actually [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) and it is not standard C, but GNU C extension.